# Can I check if a person already 'Liked' My facebook page? 'Like Button for the Web'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

So I was using this code to generate a like button for my website.
I got the code from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
But I want to show the content of my page (show div .hello), only if the person who is visiting my website, already has a like on my webpage. I searched alot about this, but it's everything old solutions that don't work anymore, or are solutions for the websites that use API to log in with facebook, etc.

On my javascript down there, i tried to identify the div #u_0_6, because that is the one with the like button, and it gets the 'active' class if the person already liked it. But, this doesn't work because facebook loads after, i believe. Anyone can help me out? Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
.hello{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=230541230777198";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<br>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="v" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

<div class="hello"><p>Hello</p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    if ($("#u_0_6").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".hello").addClass("show")
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, Facebook forbids like-gating of this sort, and takes lots of technological measures to prevent what you're trying to do. Give it up.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks alot!